# Where to outsource smart contract developers, and how to manage them as start-up's CEO?

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, dapp-development, contract-debugging, dapp-design

If someone has an idea for a DApp, but needs to hire programming muscle, where online can reliable and innovative smart contract developers be found for hire and outsourcing? and what etiquette and guidance procedure should a budding CEO of a start-up be aware of when presenting ideas to these contracted contract developers? i.e. contract negotiation: how to put a price on the Help while not knowing how long it will take them to complete the project